# Summation over one dimension of a three dimensional array using shared memory

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

I need to do calculation like:

```
A[x][y] = sum{from z=0 till z=n}{B[x][y][z]+C[x][y][z]}
```

where matrix `A` has dimensions `[height][width]` and tensors `B` and `C` have dimensions `[height][width][n]`.

Values are mapped to memory with something like:

```
index = 0;
for (z = 0; z<n; ++z)
    for(y = 0; y<width; ++y)
        for(x = 0; x<height; ++x) {
            matrix[index] = value;
            index++;
        }
```

I would like to each block calculate one sum since each block has its own shared memory. To avoid data races I use `atomicAdd`, something like this:

Part of host code:

```
dim3 block (n, 1, 1);
dim3 grid (height, width, 1);
```

Kernel:

```
atomicAdd( &(A[blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.y]), 
           B[blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.y+threadIdx.x*blockDim.x*blockDim.y] 
           + C[blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.y+threadIdx.x*blockDim.x*blockDim.y] );
```

I would like to use shared memory for calculating the sum and then copy this result to global memory.

I am not sure how to do the part with shared memory. In each block´s shared memory will be stored just one number ( sum result ). How should I copy this number to the right place in matrix `A` in global memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need shared memory or atomic memory access to do the summation you are asking about. If I have understood this correctly, your data is in column major order, so the logical operation is to have one thread per matrix entry in the output matrix, and have each thread traverse the z axis of the input matrices, summing as they go. The kernel for this could look something like:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *A, const float *B, const float *C, 
        const int width, const int height, const int n)
{
    int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int tidy = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

    if ( (tidx < height) && (tidy < width) ) {
        int stride = width * height;
        int ipos = tidx + tidy * height;

        float * oval = A + ipos;
        float sum = 0.f;
        for(int z=0; z<n; z++, ipos+=stride) {
            sum += B[ipos] + C[ipos];
        }
        *oval = sum;
    }
}
```

This approach should be optimal for column-major data with `width * height >= n`. There are no performance advantages to using shared memory for this, and there is no need to use atomic memory operations either. If you had a problem where `width * height << n` it might make sense to try a block wise parallel reduction per summation. But you have not indicated what the typical dimensions of the problem are. Leave a comment if your problem is more like the latter, and I can add a reduction based sample kernel to the answer.

Comment: but when each thread traverse the z axis of the input matrices the calculation is serialized, isn´t it?

Comment: each thread compute value in z=0 then move to z=1 and so on. this is serialized. and for each z there has to by acces to global memory. I´d like to aviod it.

Comment: how I understand your code: it starts in plane z=0. every element in plane z=0 is readed from global. then is calculated the result and is stored in global memory. then it shifts to z=1. every element in plane z=1 is readed from global. then is calculated the result which is added (read and write to global memory) to previous result in global memory. then it shifts to z=2 ... if this is right there is serialization and access to global memory in every addition.

Comment: In the kernel, there is only one global memory write per output entry in `A`. Each thread performs `n` reads from both `B` and `C`. Every entry in `B` and `C` is read exactly once. There is no more efficient way to do this operation.

Comment: Err that is 20Gb worth of input matrices, assuming you are using a 32 bit type. NVIDIA don't make a GPU with that much memory. What is your *actual* problem size?

Comment: sry, there is some resizing during my computation but for this case height=width=64 and n=9604

Comment: if you have `512x512xn` inputs, then the code in my answer is the best way to go. if you had `8x8x10^6`, then a reduction based strategy would make sense.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your answer and comments. One last question. I do not understand this part: `float * oval = A + ipos;`. why you can not assigned sum to `A`?

Comment: `float * oval = A + ipos; ... ; *oval=sum` has the same effect as `A[ipos]=sum`, except that we don't need the initial value of ipos to do it - the code just is pre-calculating the address where the sum will need to be stored so `ipos` can be changed in the loop.

Comment: @pavan: I would do that if n was really large and the xy dimensions were small, or if the array was in row major order. But for column major order this is probably still the best approach. It should be memory throughput limited, and as long as everything is coalesced and L1 cache friendly, it is pretty hard to do better. I would probably unroll the loop and introduce some intermediate sums if n was well known in advance. That would open up more scope for ILP on compute 2.1 and 3.0 devices.

Comment: @talonmies, N doesn't have to be really large, xy need not be real small, infact x*y  can be treated as a single dimension. Whatever benefits you get from coalesced accesses and L1 cache are also applicable to reductions. The only real trade off would be reduced operations (n vs log(n)) and  `__syncthreads` (about 3-5 of them, since you are syncing along y dimension) vs `#pragma unroll`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I think the solution is great if we know the value of `n`, small. Even better if it is templated and unrolled. I was just trying to make a point that n does not need to be large, just greater than 32 may be enough to gain performance benefits.

Comment: @Pavan, so if n=9604 and height=width=64 what is your sugestion to make code better?